# Debug translations - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, inline-translations

1. some strings on the site are not translated. are present in the translation dictionary and apparently correctly compiled. what could be your problem?
2. I forced some of these strings using online translation (admin tool) but when I make deploy the translated strings comes back in English. I have to use online translation again - change one string only and save - and at this point they all return in italian

most of these strings are in the checkout pages

how can I do a complete debugging of untranslated strings?

Comment: It looks like a hint to me "most of these strings are in the checkout pages". Most of the strings in checkout come from the js translations file which is js-translation.json and it is created when the static content is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have translated the strings through inline translation it is possible to delete the rows from the database. If you easily want to manage your translations in the Magento Admin Panel you could use this free module

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-MissingTranslations

This module will add the following feature

> Add a CLI command to Collect missing translations in specified folder
>   or the entire Magento 2 Root and add Admin Grid to display and update
>   database/inline translations (Stores > Translations > Database/Inline
>   Translations)

Comment: I hope this is any help for you! If you want more information please provide more information if it is about js or different translations?